# Disable live event on current method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In the view I have the following class

```
.class{"data-id" => time.id}
```

At the end of the view I enable the live click event

```
$('.class').live("click", function() {
    window.orc.time.stopCount();
    window.orc.time.whenClicked(#{class.id}, #{class.time}, #    
{class.start});});
```

In coffeescript i have the following function

```
time.whenClicked = (class.id, time_dur, time_start) -> 
   ct = time_entries.to_time(time_dur, time_start)
   $("div[data-id=#{time_id}]").addClass "ajax"
   $("div[data-id=#{time_id}]").html("<input id=\"editbox\" size=\"8\" type=\"text\" value=\"#{ct}\">") 
   $("#editbox").bind "keyup", (event) ->
     ...
```

In the whenClicked function I need the live("click") to be disabled. If I try

```
$(".class").die("click")
```

it works, but then the click event will be re-enabled only after I refresh the page, and that's not what I need.

Is there a solution to disable the click event untill the function is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't disable the handler. Just implement a boolean flag so you know if the method is already running or not. You can then immediately return from the handler in that case:

```
var isBusy = false;

$('.class').live('click', function(){
    if(isBusy) return;
    isBusy = true;
    window.orc.time.stopCount();
    window.orc.time.whenClicked(/* some params */);
    isBusy = false;
});
```